# TransformedRegion, RegionPlot broken in 10.0.2.0?

Tags: version-10, regions, plotting

After having had trouble applying `TranslationTransform` to a simple region like so

```
RegionPlot[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[],TranslationTransform[{2,0}]]]
```

I tried to find my error by researching *Mathematica's* online documentation, specifically ref/TransformedRegion. After having failed to find a glitch in my code, I just did an "Evaluate Notebook" from the "Evaluation" menu, with a discouraging result:

1. Error messages: `RegionPlot::nnregion`, `RegionPlot::invplotreg`, `TransformedRegion::reg`, `DiscretizeRegion::regp`, `RegionDistance::regp`, `Volume::reg`, `Integrate::ilim`, `MinValue::elemc`, `Reduce::elemc`, `RegionBounds::reg`, `RegionDistance::regp` (in that order).
2. Different `RegionPlot`-outputs, which, as comments showed, are due to wrong `PlotRange` (so, there is a workaround for this by manually changing that option).

**My question is:** Is my 10.0.2.0 installation damaged or might this be a problem with *Mathematica* itself?

I have the same results on two machines (Windows 7 and Windows 8.1, both 64bit).

### Examples

**Before evaluating the documentation page**

[image: before evaluation]
[image: before evaluation 2]
[image]

**After**

[image: after evaluation]
[image: after evaluation 2]
[image]

Comment: A damaged installation, likely not. It's a miscalculated default `PlotRegion`, that's all.

Comment: @rcollyer: You may be right, but the display (especially the closed boundaries) are highly misleading. In that state, the region plotting functionality is not really usable with TransformedRegion.

Comment: @rcollyer: And the error messages resulting from processing the documentation page indicate, that there **is** something wrong here.

Comment: I don't contest those conclusions, just the conclusion that it is a damaged installation. You can verify that it is the `PlotRange` by setting `PlotRange -> {{-1, 0.6}, {0, 1.4}}` for the first example and `PlotRange -> {{-8, 15}, {-4, 8}}` for the second.

Comment: @rcollyer: I take it you have the same behavior (error messages, `PlotArea`-problem) when evaluating the online documentation reference page?

Comment: On recent sources, I don't see the error messages. But, I do see more "interesting" things ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20638/discussion-between-jinxed-and-rcollyer).

Comment: You must be Jinxed.

Comment: Can you describe more accurately what the problem is here?  It would be best to write is as "I evaluated this command", "I expected this result", "I got this result instead".  I am working with 11.0 and it's not clear to me what your problem was and what has changed since the version you were using at that time.  Others are asking about it. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130744/12

Comment: @Szabolcs: I thought this would be rather clear (bolded lines "Before evaluating the documentation page", "After" etc.): I re-evaluated a documentation notebook in Mathematica, and received the displayed results. I _expected_ the results to stay as they were.
Possible cause: Mathematica documentation seems to be generated with different settings than delivered to users, but that is just an assumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem Confirmed

Wolfram has confirmed this to be a problem with *Mathematica* 10.0.2.0, not a damaged installation. There is no known workaround for now.

Transcript of the confirmation mail (dated 2015-01-28):

> ```
> Hello -
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> I have filed a report with our developers on this issue with 
> TransformedRegion so that they are aware of the problem.
> This may allow them to fix the problem in a future version of
> Mathematica.  I am not aware of any workarounds for this 
> problem at the current time, but I will be sure to pass on
> any useful information should it become available.
> Please let me know if you have any further questions. 
>
> ~[name masked]~
> Technical Support
> Wolfram Research, Inc.
> http://support.wolfram.com
> ```