# why RegionPlot has cut in ring when changing plot range?

Tags: plotting

I am not sure I understand this one, thought to check with the experts.  Please compare

```
ClearAll[x, y]
RegionPlot[0.5 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.75, {x, -2.5, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
        Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with

```
ClearAll[x, y]
RegionPlot[0.5 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.75, {x, -3, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
      Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the x range was just increased a little in the second case. I did not think this should affect the output.  What Am I missing?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RegionPlot[0.5 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.75, {x, -3, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: thanks. I would never have guessed it is the plot points. But this is not really a good way for `RegionPlot` to handle these things. How is the user supposed to know if the result is due to low number of sampling points internally or if the result is actually the region they should get?

Comment: Well, `PlotPoints` rears its head frequently, especially in complicated functions in `Plot3D`.  *Mathematica* uses `PlotPoints -> Automatic` as a default (of course), where the internal number is computed based on some measure of the detail in the function itself.  I too am a bit surprised that for such a simple annular region *Mathematica* didn't figure out the needed resolution or number of points.  A good rule of thumb is to check on important figures by setting `PlotPoints` high, and if you don't get new graphical information, revert to `Automatic`.

Comment: Be aware, though, that there might be more severe issues with `RegionPlot`: [TransformedRegion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72666/24763)